# How to open a new tab in browser with other url in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to open url from current webpage in a new tab in the browser. How can we open a new tab from a controller action.

```
public ActionResult AddDocumentControls(int DocInfo)
        {
     url="www.test.com";   
if(DocInfo==1)
{
open the url in a new tab
}
}
```

I tried

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('url','_newtab');", true);
```

but Page.ClientScript is not getting here.

can anyone give me some help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are invoking `AddDocumentControls` action from anchor or actionlink then set its `target=_blank` attribute.

Comment: some other functionalities are there in AddDocumentControls .so I need the structure linke this only.

Comment: you can call a javascript function on anchor/actionlink click and check `docinfo` there if its `1` then use `window.open` or add `target=_blank` with jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
  @Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", new {controller="Controller"}, new {target="_blank"})



  <a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

Javascript method,

```
window.open("Link URL")
```